# Difference between Fm and H

Tags: magnetic-flux

What's the difference between magnetomotive force(MMF)(Fm) and magnetizing force (the strength of the magnetizing field)(H) ?

Comment: H=F/l per unit length, l [m]

Answer (score 0):

H (magnetising force) is in units of amps per metre.

F (magnetomotive force) is in units of amps.

Apart from the per distance thing, they are essentially the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Magnetic field strength (H with units of ampere (turns) per metre) is the intensity of a magnetic field just as electric field strength (E in volts per metre) is an intensity of an electric field. Both (H and E) are the fields that create an electromagnetic field.

MMF is just ampere (turns) and so is not a field quantity.

H gives rise to magnetic flux density via the magnetic permeability of the material it is associated with. You cannot calculate flux density with MMF alone - you need a material specification (iron, ferrite, air etc.) and a path length.